# Wordpress Widget plugin and input file

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget

I am writing a widget plugin for Wordpress and I want to insert an input tag:`<input type="file">` to browse for a pattern in my widget plugin admin panel; but I have problem to save its value.

It seems that `<input type="file">` doesn't work in widget plugins. Is it correct? Are there any other ways to browse a file from the admin panel?

Comment: Your message is not really clear. Could you edit it?

Comment: @JonesV, thanks for your comment!
it's important for me to know the reason of the language corrections.
So, what about my main question?

Comment: I don't understand the "browse for a pattern" part. Don't you simply want to allow the user to select a file from her disk?

Comment: @JonesV, something like this!
I want to let the user to select an image such as a pattern from his webserver.
to get address of the image for its display.

Answer (score 0):

I made it using combination of arbitrary file input and hidden input for image path. Here're the steps:

1. create hidden field that will be saved and dummy file input
2. bind [change event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) to file input (I'm using jQuery)
3. on change collect [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) and send it via ajax to [ajaxurl](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side)
4. add `action('wp_ajax_hook', 'my_callback_func')` in functions.php, where hook = your action
5. [move uploaded file(s)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to [upload dir](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir#Description)
6. return file path from `my_callback_func`
7. [fill hidden field](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) with file path on [ajax success](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)
8. display uploaded image for user, so that he konws upload was successful (optional)
9. PROFIT!!! Now you can save you form

I will not post code snippets here, cause they are rather trivial for most developers